# Tags own pane that is auto generated?

Tags: org-tags

Is there a way to gather all the tags used in an `org-mode` file, 
and it displays these on a dedicated side pane?

Comment: You may want to reword the title question. I think people confuse Org tags with TAGS (files used to navigate source code). Also, what about `C-c a M`? See more here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties

Answer (score 1):

I use this to generate a table of clickable links:

```
#+NAME: all-tags
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(let ((new (list)))
  (dolist (tag (org-global-tags-completion-table))
    (setq tag (car tag))
    (push (concat "[[tag:" tag "][" tag "]]\n") new))
  (sort new 'string<))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: all-tags
| [[tag:3d][3d]]      |
| [[tag:Android][Android]] |
| [[tag:Apple][Apple]]   |
| [[tag:Arch][Arch]]    |
```

along with this link style:

```
(org-add-link-type "tag" 
  (lambda (tag) "Show tag" org-tags-view nil tag)))
```

It shouldn't be too hard to make that open in a separate frame.